# Django dropdown list - change to None during edit

Tags: django

I have a model with month choice field (from January to December). When I want to edit model by generic UpdateView, field with month is shown by '----', but I don't want to change the month. Is there a proper way to display in form month that was decalared when creating object?

In model:

```
months_choice =(
("1": "January",)
("2": "February",)

and so on
)
date = models.CharField(max_length=3,
    choices=months_choice)
```

Rendered form shows this:

[I want display here the month that was declared earlier]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUys8.png

Comment: does the code below answer your questions ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. When I was adding objects, month field was saved as month name, e.g. "January", but had to be saved as "1". Now everything works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).